# Tomcat: Redirect a Rest Call and use part of the URL to build the parameters

Tags: tomcat, redirect

I have an Apache Tomcat server and I need a solution (inside or outside tomcat) to transform the Rest call for instance from  "/equipment/instance/{id}/state" to "/myObjects/myInstance/state?id={id}". Is there an easy way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I added an Nginx server as a reverse proxy to handle this. I configured a 'rewrite' and it seems to be working well.

Here is the Nginx configuration:

```
    server {
        listen 81;

       location /mission {
          rewrite ^/equipment/instance/(.*)/state$ http://10.10.10.10:8080/MyServer/myObjects/myInstance/state?testInput=$1 redirect;
       }
```

Comment: Can you share the configuration changes you made? Answers here aren't just supposed to solve the immediate problem, but to help future users with the same question. Please read [answer].